# fprintf() and fputs() not getting the right results

Tags: c, string, file, printf, output

Good evening people. I am trying to print strings into a result file, however things aren't going very well. 
For example the contents of my data file are:

```
Hello, today
is a
Good Day
What is going
On here?
```

and the result file turns out to show:

```
On here?

g
```

This is my printing function:

```
void print(char B[])
{
    printf("%s", B); //NOTE; this string represents a line of data file and works!
    FILE *wfile;
    if ((wfile = fopen("result.txt","w")) == NULL){
       printf("File did not open!!!/n");
       exit(1);
   }
   fprintf(wfile, "%s", B);
}
```

I am at a loss guys, any kind of input is greatly appreciated.

Comment: your `fopen` mode is "w" (write), you probably want to change it to append. Also you should `fclose` the file after writing to it.

Comment: You also may want to consider perhaps opening the file at the start of your program and passing in the FILE* to your print function so you can print multiple times without opening and closing the file repeatedly

Comment: I LOVE YOU PEOPLE!! Finally, it works, and ofcourse it was the easiest fix in the world.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the commenters, I have realised that instead of

```
if ((wfile = fopen("result.txt","w")) == NULL)
```

I had to change the "w" to "a" since I want to append strings to the file

```
if ((wfile = fopen("result.txt","a")) == NULL)
```